# Parse CC - success callback not firing

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've created a Cloud Code function for creating a new Stripe customer, which works okay. What I can't figure out is the returning of the customer ID to the calling code;

### Calling Code

```
Parse.Cloud.run(
    'createCustomer',
    {
        email: user.get('email'),
        username: user.get('username')
    },
    {
        success: function(customerId) {
            // never called
            console.log('Customer created: ' + customerId);
        },
        error: function() {
            console.log('Error function');
        }
    }
);
```

### Function

```
Parse.Cloud.define(
    'createCustomer',
    function(request, response) {

        var email = request.params.email,
            description = 'Username: ' + request.params.username;

        Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) {

            var Stripe = require('stripe');
            Stripe.initialize(config.get('stripe_secret_test'));

            Stripe.Customers.create({
                description: description,
                email: email
            })
            .then(function(customer) {
                console.log(customer.id); // Logs out fine
                response.success(customer.id);
            });
        });
    }
);
```

Basically, the success callback in the calling code is never fired, so I can't access the customer ID I want to return. What am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Cloud functions don't seem to play well if called from within Cloud Code, they run but I couldn't find a way to return a value.

Instead I used a [Cloud Code Module](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-advanced-modules), since this function only ever needed to be called from within Cloud Code. Final code is below;

### Calling Code (User beforeSave)

```
var createCustomerModule = require('cloud/stripe/CreateCustomer.js');

createCustomerModule.createCustomer(
    user.get('email'),
    user.get('username'),
    {
        success: function(customer) {
            request.object.set('stripeCustomerId', customer.id);
            response.success();
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error('Failed to create a new Stripe customer');
        }
    }
);
```

### Function (cloud/stripe/CreateCustomer.js)

```
exports.createCustomer = function(email, username, callbacks) {

    var description = 'Username: ' + username;

    Parse.Config.get().then(function(config) {

        var Stripe = require('stripe');
        Stripe.initialize(config.get('stripe_secret_test'));

        // Attempt to create the customer
        Stripe.Customers.create({
            description: description,
            email: email
        })
        .then(callbacks.success, callbacks.error);
    });
};
```